# How can I remove the " is dangerous, so Chrome has blocked it" block from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-s3, https, exe

For the last four years we have offered a trial version of our Windows desktop application. The set-up file can be downloaded and installed by those who are interested.

Recently Chrome has started blocking the download with the message, "is dangerous, so Chrome has blocked it". The download link is a direct https link to an Amazon S3 bucket. The file passes virus-total scans and certainly isn't dangerous. The user can configure Chrome to eventually download the file; or use another browser. But such a message is bound to put off many prospective clients.

**What do I need to do to ensure the warning is removed?**

The download page is https://www.alignmix.com/download

Steve

Answer (score -1):

In the upper right corner, click the vertical ellipsis to open Chrome's settings. Type safe browsing in the search box, and tinker with the enhanced/standard settings. Screen grab in URL below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWIjY.png

Comment: And Ctr+Shift+B is hiding your bookmark bar so you don't have to paint it ;)